# Hierarchical outline of posts

Tags: categories

Is this possible? --

Hierarchical outline / menu (preferably not in nav) that helps visitor find their way through ~200 articles, organized into Topics / Sub-Topics / Sub-Sub-Topics / Articles. A single page with nested dropdowns would fit the bill if not too messy, and multiple menu pages would also be acceptable.

Can either system of hierarchically organized links-to-articles be a static Page/s that link to articles-as-individual-Posts? The goal is for the individual articles / Posts to appear as stand-alone "pages" with SEO-friendly URLs, not just as sections of one huge, master Post.

Help appreciated!

Comment: you need a single specific question that can be answered factually, this isn't a discussion forum so asking multiple subjective questions severely hurts your chances of an answer and could get your question closed as offtopic. Can you edit it down to a single specific question? One that can be answered without opinions? Use the edit link under the tags to do this

Comment: Thanks. Edited.